# LCD Custom Character

Tags: lcd

I am experimenting the `write((byte)num)` function, and I stumble upon a pre-made custom character. Usually it's on above `((byte)200)` or and below `((byte)10000)`. If anyone else know this, where could I find the list for a specific character?

Comment: Post the code and the output.  You're talking nonsense with a byte with a value of 10000.  A byte can't have a value that high.

Comment: @Delta_G  I think that `(byte) 10000` is a cast of integer to byte ... it is equal to 16

Comment: https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/LCD/HD44780.pdf pages 17 and 18 (depending on what ROM your LCD has). And the range is 128-255 - the "high bit set" on ASCII.

Comment: Yes, @jstola, that was exactly my point.  There is no character at 10000, he needs to be thinking of what number is actually being used there.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Welcome to Arduino StackExchange

You can build your own LCD characters if you spend some time with the datasheet and user manuals available

Arduino has a dedicated function **[here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/LiquidCrystalCreateChar)**

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

byte smiley[8] = {
  B00000,
  B10001,
  B00000,
  B00000,
  B10001,
  B01110,
  B00000,
};

void setup() {
  lcd.createChar(0, smiley);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);  
  lcd.write(byte(0));
}

void loop() {}
```

here is one **example**:  from our tool [here](https://goodarduinocode.com/projects/electronic-safe)

[image]

From the **[datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/LCD/HD44780.pdf)**:
[image]

here is one example where a Heart symbol is created using the built-in Arduino LCD library:

You can play [here](https://wokwi.com/playground/lcd1602-i2c) at our LCD1602 simulator to get a hang of it.  Please leave a message or comment if you have any questions :)
[image]